# How long does Turkish Airlines take for a flight refund?

Tags: refunds, turkish-airlines

Recently booked a ticket to Glasgow through Turkish Airlines and had to cancel the booking as I've inputed the wrong date. I called the airline operator and they said I was eligible for a full refund, so went ahead with the option. Was wondering how long would they take to process a refund request.

Also wondering if anybody has experienced refund with Turkish Airlines before?

I'm currently residing in Singapore, so I had to call the Singapore branch office and they directed me to the International office. It's best to call the branch office in the country you're residing in.

Comment: Did you try to check the airline website? I found this at the top of the Google search. http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/travel-information/legal-notice/terms-amp-conditions/cancellation-refund

Comment: Yes I did. I couldn't find an approximate time length for their refunds except for purchasing  the ticket by iDEAL or Sofort

Comment: This airline treats money paid for cancelled tickets due to coronavirus as their own. I received no refund from April and I need to go to court with this issue. No respect for clients and I would say even fraud. Better to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

Turkish Airlines practice on refunds varies, according to the method of purchase and the ticket terms and conditions. Refunds are affected by the policy of issuer of credit card that was used for payment, so you would have to check that, as well.

> Cancellations/refunds and changes Learn more >>
>
> [Ticket cancellations/refunds and changes not made through Online Channels](https://p.turkishairlines.com/en-us/legal-notice/conditions-of-online-channels/index.html):
>
> - Tickets in which the first leg of the trip has been made.
> - Tickets issued though other channels, such as Our sales offices, call centers or agents.
> - Tickets purchased via EFT or internet banking.
> - Changes to award tickets.
> - Multi-city flights.
>
> In cases where ticket cancellations/refunds and changes are not made through Online Channels, please contact Our call center or visit a Turkish Airlines Sales Office in order to cancel, request a refund or change a ticket.
>
> Any ticket refunds will be made according to the payment method used while purchasing the ticket.
>
> All deductions, taxes or price differences, ticketing service fees, etc. will be calculated automatically when making cancellations, changes or requesting a refund.
>
> Refunds made to iDEAL and Sofort accounts will be processed within around 5 days.
>
> The refund period for other payment methods will depend on the existing agreements with the relevant institutions.
>
> Your cancellation/refund and change requests will be applied to all passengers listed under Your reservation. Separate transactions cannot be carried out for individual passenger under a reservation.
>
> Confirmation of cancellations/refunds and changes made through Online Channels will be sent via e-mail.
>
> [**When do I receive a refund for tickets purchased online**?](https://p.turkishairlines.com/en-us/any-questions/when-do-i-receive-a-refund-for-tickets-purchased-online/index.html)
>
> Refunds for tickets purchased online are issued either immediately or within a specified time period depending on the type of credit card used for payment.

As you say that you put in the wrong date(s), have you contacted the airline regarding correcting the error? It may be willing to make the adjustment (free or for a fee), depending on the terms and conditions of the ticket that you purchased.

Comment: Yes I did called the airline. They said I was eligible for a full refund, therefore I went ahead with that refund. They also gave me an computer generated email regarding my refund.

Comment: @Nadia excellent; why don't you add that as an update to your question (hit the word edit) so that those who have a similar question can see the the resolution. It would help to add some more details (what you 'bought' and why the full refund, the number you called).